# 2d sprite bone rigging

Tags: animation

I have a question. Is it possible to draw a sprite from a side view and then rig that with bones? Maybe I would first have to import the image into blender and then dop that outline with a mesh. Then, if even possible, I could maybe attach the sprite to the mesh and add the bones. I dont really have much experience with blender but I did create a humanoid sculpture and successfully rig it a long time ago. I don't remember being able to paste an image to the mesh in blender, but I do remember something having to do with seams and then maybe I could export those parts and attach it to them in another program (or worse have to draw over them which means having to draw the image all over again.) I'm not much of an art guy, more of a coding guy. I use Unity and would like to only have to draw one image and then do all the animations of that one image in blender so that I can focus more on coding. If it is possible please let me know. Thank you in advance for any response.

Comment: Sure possible. You could use the "Import Images as Planes" addon bundled with blender, you could also use Inkscape and Blender to import the sprites as curves and there are many more possible ways that come in mind. Your question sounds more like a tutorial request. See [this](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?330479-Ron-amp-Obi-Exploring-2D-animation-in-Blender), [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d7u5OE8YhPU) or [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htFYQcvHXUs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get started with your project you could enable the addon *Import Images as Planes* in Menu: *File / User Preferences*.

It will be accessible from the menu *File / Import / Image as Plane* and create a plane an UVMap and assigns the image texture. 
Note: You need to set the Viewport Shading to texture otherwise you won't see the image texture.

[image]

Bones are used to deform geometry you should ask another question (perhaps add an illustration) on what exactly you want to achieve.

[image]

You can tweak the subdivided edges in the *UV-Editor* and scale to maintain the proportions. Separating <kbd>P</kbd> *By Selection* for e.g. the legs allows you to have single objects for this part of the image which can be animated using bones as shown in the image above.

Comment: Yea couldn't I subdivide the plane with the texture plane and assign the vertices to a specific bone? The problem I have with importing a texture as a plane will be that it will be a square. I don't need that I need just my character which obviously wont be squared.

Comment: @luigi You can subdivide or loop-cut the mesh in edit mode. Updated answer