# Can I rig a 2d character that I made in Illustrator with Blender?

Tags: rigging

I've created a 2D character in Illustrator that I would like apply a rig to. Is it possible to import the file into Blender and apply a rig?

Comment: like this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8516/2d-sprite-bone-rigging ?

Comment: Export your vectorial drawing from Illustrator as SVG.
Enable the Import-Export Scalable Vector Graphics in blender, and import the SVG files.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.blendernation.com/2012/01/09/2d-in-blender-2-6-tutorial/) might interest you as well.