# 3D Animation to 2D Animation

Tags: animation, rigging

I hope you can help me out.
I have to create a 2D Animation with People and the fastest way would be, when I take some finished animation like some Motion Capture data and put them into the rig BUT the Motion Capture data is in a 3D World so what would be the best way to put the 3D movement into a 2D movement. Just to lock the x or y axes would not help I think.

Comment: What you see on your 3d view  in blender **is** a  2D representation of 3D data.  Needs some clarification on what point of view you use for converting 3d to 2d.

Comment: the modell is a vector graphic of a human and it can just move in 2 direction

Comment: [Edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/110305/edit) details into your question.  Is there any perceivable difference between moving directly toward / away from  the camera and scaling up / down, if there are no other objects for reference?  [Related?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8516/2d-sprite-bone-rigging)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://youtu.be/HjwC5HYA0QY using CrazyTalk animator 3
Or https://youtu.be/apQLz15HPLU
Using IKinema